# Can't change selected view in Picker View

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I can't change the selected view from `pickerView` when it is shown for the first time.

Also, I tried to call the `didSelectRow` delegate method directly after the `selectRow` method in `viewDidLoad`, but nothing happens.

When I normally swipe the picker it works as expected - selected item changed as described in `didSelectRow` method.

But I can't figure how to change the selected view for the first time, without user interaction.

```swift
// start - pikerView

let viewStart = self.start.view(forRow: self.startInex, forComponent: 0)
viewStart?.backgroundColor = .red
```

Comment: pickerView.selectRow(10,inComponent: 0, animated: false)

Answer (score 0):

In line with the other comments, I'm not sure why you are having issues, but here is a simple implementation that shows creating a 3-column, 5-row picker and then setting all columns (components) to the 3rd row.

```
class MyVC: UIViewController{
   let pickerRows = 5
   let pickerColumns = 3
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      let picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:100, width:  400, height: 400))
      view.addSubview(picker)
      view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
      picker.dataSource = self
      picker.delegate = self
      (0..<pickerColumns).map{picker.selectRow(3, inComponent: $0, animated: true)}
   }
}

extension MyVC: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
   public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        pickerColumns
     }

     public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        pickerRows
     }

     public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        switch (row, component) {
        case (_, 0): return "Row \(row)"
        case (_, _): return "\(component) - \(row)"
        }
     }
}
```